# How to calculate the exponential of a matrix?

Tags: calculus

Can anyone please give me an example of how to calculate the exponential of a matrix given its Jordan canonical form?

Comment: $e^A = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{A^n}{n!}$

Comment: The basic situation is the diagonalizable case, where if $A=P D P^{-1}$ then $e^A=P e^D P^{-1}$, where $e^D$ is just a diagonal matrix with $e^{D_{ii}}$ as its diagonal entries. The nondiagonalizable case is essentially the same: if $J$ is the Jordan form, then $A=P J P^{-1}$ and $e^A = P \left ( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{J^n}{n!} \right ) P^{-1}$. The sum in the middle will be much like the previous one, except that it may take a certain finite number of terms before the Jordan blocks are all diagonal.

Comment: merci mais je voulais dire un exemple concret on'a 
$$e^{tJ_{ \lambda_{j}}}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
e^{t J_{ \lambda_{j}}}& te^{t J_{ \lambda_{j}}}&..&e^{t{s_{j}}}\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\
&&&&\\
&&&e^{ts_{j}}\\
&&&&&\\
&&....&e^{ts}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ \\ je veux un exemple avec des nobmres si il est .possible

Comment: You may take a look at http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf where, in my opinion, it is very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

We note that the Jordan Decomposition of a matrix is given by:

$$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{S}\mathbf{J}\mathbf{S}^{-1},$$

Where $\mathbf{S}$ is the change of basis matrix and the $\mathbf{J}$ is the Jordan Canonical Form. We now note that the exponential of a matrix is defined by the equation:

$$\exp\left(\mathbf{A}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbf{A}^{n}}{n!}$$

We also note that we have:

$$\mathbf{A}^{n} = \left(\mathbf{S}\mathbf{J}\mathbf{S}^{-1}\right)^{n} = \mathbf{S}\mathbf{J}\mathbf{S}^{-1}\mathbf{S}\cdots\mathbf{S}^{-1}\mathbf{S}\mathbf{J}\mathbf{S}^{-1}=\mathbf{S}\mathbf{J}^{n}\mathbf{S}^{-1}$$

Thus we can write:

$$\exp\left(\mathbf{A}\right)=\mathbf{S}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbf{J}^{n}}{n!}\right)\mathbf{S}^{-1}$$

The term in the middle is trivial for diagonalizable matrices and slightly more complex for non-diagonalizable matrices.